# Scale and align photos within a box

Tags: image, ember.js, alignment, scale, crop

I am creating a photo web application on mobile that allows users to upload a photo at a time. Like how instagram does it for manually uploading a photo from the user's gallery, I want to specify a box which would then allow the user to scale and align within the box. What appears in the box will then be cropped and uploaded to my backend server (parse). I am developing this application on emberjs (pretty new to this). May I know what is the best way of doing so?

Comment: we are not here to make your work, but rather help you fix specific problems you may encounter along the way. Want have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, because I am new, I am just trying to build an app on my own. I am using cordova. But cordova doesnt support any of the above mentioned.